# html 5 audio tag lower width won't show play button in chrome

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I want to use HTML 5 audio tag for both chrome and firefox:

```html
      <audio controls preload="metadata" style=" width:50px;  border-radius: 100px;margin-top: 15px; float: left;">
        <source src="https://s4.uupload.ir/filelink/MeiZSg8dmNUl_a0ba664242/koe_no_katachi_a_silent_voice_-_lit_(feora_remix)_pe7w.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
```

But when i use chrome it doesnt show the play/pause button like firefox it shows timeline which i tried to remove it with:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none !important;}
```

And the 3 dots button holds the play, download, and mute button. I don't want to use any javascript code to make a play/pause button I just want to use CSS and HTML.
How can I show the play button for the lower width like `50px` in chrome just like firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) regarding the `<audio>` element:

> The  element has no intrinsic visual output of its own unless the controls attribute is specified, in which case the browser's default controls are shown.
>
> The default controls have a display value of inline by default, and it is often a good idea set the value to block to improve control over positioning and layout, unless you want it to sit within a text block or similar.
>
> You can style the default controls with properties that affect the
> block as a single unit, so for example you can give it a border and
> border-radius, padding, margin, etc. **You can't however style the
> individual components inside the audio player (e.g. change the button
> size or icons, change the font, etc.), and the controls are different
> across the different browsers.**
>
> To get a consistent look and feel across browsers, you'll need to
> create custom controls; these can be marked up and styled in whatever
> way you want, and then JavaScript can be used along with the
> [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) API to wire up their functionality.